# Css left:100% going beyond the device screen size

Tags: html, css

I am fairly new to web-development so it could be something very novice that I am doing wrong.

**Question :** I am trying to add a circle to the top-right position. For this I am making a `div` and giving it `100px height` and `width` with `border radius 50%` to make a circle and to move to right I am doing `left 100%`.

What I expect is my browser shows me a circle on **top-right**, instead what happens is my browser introduces a scroll bar and pushes the circle to further right.

Here is the code that I have tried along with screenshots of the problem I am facing.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Scenario 6</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <style type="text/css">
      #circle {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        border: 2px solid red;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background-color: red;
        position: absolute;
        left: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="circle"></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Expected - [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJUzV.png]
Actual - [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4bFg.png]

I do not know that if this is some browser zoom error or something wrong in the code. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It is happening for "left:100%;" use instead "left:auto; right:0;".

Comment: Because when you give "left:100%" that means you taking left space 100% of container then start the element position so it become 100% + element size, hope you get the matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Scenario 6</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
 <style type="text/css">
    #circle {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        border: 2px solid red;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background-color: red;
        position: absolute;
        left: calc(100% - 100px);
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="circle"></div>
</body>
  
</html>
```

For left position you have to add `left: calc(100% - 100px)`. 100px minus because your box has 100px width and add `box-sizing: border-box;`

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you have set `left: 100%;` on `#circle`. So the circle started to draw from `startX = 100% width of screen` (left = 100%) position. Therfore, it can be drawn outside of the screen.

Instead of `left: 100%;`, use `right: 0` and the problem will be resolved.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Scenario 6</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
  <style type="text/css">
    #circle {
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      border: 2px solid red;
      border-radius: 50%;
      background-color: red;
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="circle"></div>
</body>

</html>
```